# Is T Test the proper method to compare two character frequency tables?

Tags: frequency

Given two sets of histogram both arranged alphabetically:
**[ A ]** containing the typical frequency of letters in the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) language
**[image]

[ B ]** containing the frequency of letters in this cryptogram (ignore character case, white spaces, and punctuations):

> Urerhcba Yrtenaq nebfr, jvgu n tenir naq fgngryl nve, naq oebhtug zr gur orrgyr
>   sebz n tynff pnfr va juvpu vg jnf rapybfrq. Vg jnf n ornhgvshy fpnenonrhf, naq, ng
>   gung gvzr, haxabja gb anghenyvfgf—bs pbhefr n terng cevmr va n fpvragvsvp cbvag
>   bs ivrj. Gurer jrer gjb ebhaq oynpx fcbgf arne bar rkgerzvgl bs gur onpx, naq n
>   ybat bar arne gur bgure. Gur fpnyrf jrer rkprrqvatyl uneq naq tybffl, jvgu nyy gur
>   nccrnenapr bs oheavfurq tbyq. Gur jrvtug bs gur vafrpg jnf irel erznexnoyr, naq,
>   gnxvat nyy guvatf vagb pbafvqrengvba, V pbhyq uneqyl oynzr Whcvgre sbe uvf bcvavba
>   erfcrpgvat vg.

Also, given that the cipher used on this cryptogram was a simple substitution cipher, how do I determine the **closeness** of the two histograms?
My end goal is to determine how many shifts do I need to make on **[ B ]** in order for it to align or best fit with **[ A ]**.
I have stumbled upon [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230939/how-to-compare-two-samples-of-frequencies), however I don't understand how should I apply it. If you would be so kind to show me the proper steps, as well as equations necessary to solve this problem, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I take it you don't just want to use pattern words? ;)